# Can a Google Storage Object be set with max age?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Can a Google Storage Object have a max age. I do not want to set the TTL at the bucket level. I looked at the api documentation, I couldnt find a property or method for this in API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not currently a feature. Right now, TTL can only be set on whole buckets.